# Compute the costs depending on the quantity with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to finish this. I know how to find out if the number is divisible by 3 but once I get above 3 how do I keep the discount plus the remainder? Example: 7 tickets cost $120

$20 each or 3 for $50

```
<input id="raffleTix" type="text" value="0" />
```

```
if($('#raffleTix').val() % 3 == 0){
    raffle = ($('#raffleTix').val() / 3) * 50;
}else if($('#raffleTix').val() < 3){
    raffle = $('#raffleTix').val() * 20;
}else{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to have any conditional logic. This can be done with a simple formula:

```
var value = $('#raffleTix').val();
var setsOfThree = Math.floor(value / 3);
var singles = value - setsOfThree * 3;

raffle = setsOfThree * 50 + singles * 20;
```

Or even better, it could all be placed in a function so that different values could be passed without modifying the code:

```
function computeCost(quantity, setSize, setCost, singleCost) {
    var sets = Math.floor(quantity / setSize);
    var singles = quantity - sets * setSize;

    return sets * setCost + singles * singleCost;
}

raffle = computeCost($('#raffleTix').val(), 3, 50, 20);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect. I was way over thinking it. Cheers!

Comment: @AaronBacon Glad I could help. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you.